# update varchar field ; Diffrence between using single quotes and with out using

Tags: sql, teradata

I am using `Teradata` as database,

Table

```
sno varchar(10) primary,
number varchar(10)
```

I was able to update number field like this

```
update ...

set number = '1'

or 

set number = 1
```

I was able to get correct result in my select query `[ had max(number) column ]`,when I updated second way  i.e `set number = 1`    with out using any cast functions.

using  this (i.e `set number = '1'` ) gives me the wrong result with my select query, with out
using cast functions

can any one explain the difference?

In short , I need difference between 
 update ...

```
set number = '1'

or 

set number = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set number = 1
```

updates the VARCHAR to '1'

```
set number = 1
```

does an automatic Teradata style typecast (right aligned within FORMAT) and sets number to '   1'.

```
SELECT (1 (VARCHAR(10))) || '#', FORMAT(1), TYPE(1);

 *** Query completed. One row found. 3 columns returned.
 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.

(1||'#')    Format(1)                      Type(1)
----------- ------------------------------ -------------
   1#       -(3)9                          BYTEINT
```

What do you expect when you query MAX(col)?
For VarChars '9' is greater than '11', if you need numeric comparison you should use a numeric datatype.

Comment: Good To know dnoeth. max(column) should pick a record with highest column value among that group. We do have some aplha numeric vaues too in that column like sr001,se002,3,4,9..